# Can't access Feature Events in InstallShield 2015

Tags: installshield

According to [documentation on feature settings in InstallShield 2015](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/FeatureSettings.htm#ref-views_3665898677_featuresevents) I should be able to set feature events, but I only have the General section, no Feature Events and no Run-Time Settings. I'm working on 2015 Professional Edition.

I've also tried adding the event handler from [InstallScript](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield22helplib/Subsystems/installshield22langref/helplibrary/LangrefFeatureEventHandlers.htm), but I don't have a "left event-category list" either.

Is there a specific setting for enabling Feature Events? Or any idea on why I can't use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a specific setting for enabling Feature Events?

Nope

> Or any idea on why I can't use them?

As per documentation reference you have provided: "Setup Design view of an **InstallScript**, **InstallScript MSI**, or **InstallScript Object** project, the following settings are available in the Feature Events area" Basically what it says, you need to create these specific types of project. You probably created "BasicMSI" type of the project, which is default I believe. Please make sure you use project type which supports InstallScript or Refer to "Sequences" section of "Behavior and Logic" of BasicMSI type of the project.

Comment: That appears to be it, working on an old Basic MSI Project, tried it on a new InstallScript Project and the Feature Events are right we're they're supposed to be. Thanks, kept reading past that detail.